# Using macro as functions in C

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor

I wanted to type in a macro that does bitwise calculations and swaps two variables

Instead of typing that code again and again in my program, I decided to use a macro as

```
#define swapVars(p,a,b) {p=a^b;a=^p;b=^p;}
```

When I use the macro in my code

```
int a = 10, b=19;
int swap_dummy = 0; //May contain anything
swapVars(swap_dummy, a, b);
printf("a = %d   | b = %d", a, b);
```

I got errors in the replacement. Is the macro definition wrong? (It should be, by the way). What is the correct macro for this situation?

Comment: You should consider writing an `inline` function instead of an macro. With Macro you loose all the *type safety*, which is rather important in this case.

Comment: Macros shouldn't have `{}` enclosures. http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Macro-Arguments.html#Macro-Arguments

Comment: This version of the xor swap fails disastrously if the input alias each other, and the macro adds an extra layer of excitement if any of the input have side effects: consider `swapVars(temp,i,j++);`. Macros simply are not functions, they are macros.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`=^` is not valid you want `^=` instead.  Although it's not clear why you are using a bit-wise  xor at all when normal assignment would work fine.

But really see the comments to your question on why this shouldn't be a macro at all.

Comment: One Question: Is inline functions  compiler-dependent? Or Is it in the standard?

Comment: @ValekHalfHeart - as the question title indicates, he is asking about C not C++.

Comment: The "inline" keyword is defined in C99, but it's more of a hint; Implementations may ignore it.

Comment: @modifiablelvalue: `inline` is not merely a hint it is a ODR relaxer.

Comment: @AlokSave Very well. `inline` is commonly used as a Norse mythological premature optimisation.

Comment: @modifiablelvalue: The fact that it is misused doesn't justify saying *`inline` is just a hint*, no it is not. Saying so undermines its purpose of existence.

Comment: @AlokSave The fact that I acknowledged that I was incorrect (eg. by saying "Very well.") doesn't qualify the humble to make a big deal.

Answer (score 2):

This question is much like "How do I solve my problem the wrong way?".

Your macro seems to be an incorrect implementation of a xor swap. Rather than help you fix your xor swap, I'm going to try to help you solve your problem the right way: Though xor-swapping is an interesting concept, there are no practical uses for it. Are you sure that's not a premature optimisation?

1. It's not idiomatic, unlike a temporary variable swap. For a start, if you had written a temporary variable swap, you wouldn't have had this problem. Furthermore, if you have to take time to explain your code to your colleagues, then you might wish to consider a more significant optimisation for your workplace.
2. It's less defined than a typical swap, in this case. Using xor on `int` values can cause trap representations such as negative zero. Using trap representations is undefined behaviour. Undefined behaviour can cause your program to malfunction in very strange ways.
3. Compilers do a better job at compiling more common and well defined code. Let your compiler do premature optimisations for you.

Regarding the `inline` keyword: Stop optimising prematurely. Get your program working correctly with simple, easy to read code so that you can ask for our help. Once you have a working solution, profile it if necessary to work out where the most significant optimisations might come from.

Comment: Respect your thought. But i am not actually practically doing this to use it in some place or something... I was just learning macro in C. And I learned many things, right?

I don't have the code right now and i am quite confused about my assignment operator implementation (Really feeling: Was my mistake that simple). 

Regarding your Last edit: I had never heard of inline functions (or keyword, whatever) until today. I would definatily learn that and as you say "Stop Optimising prematurely". Thanks for the suggestion Anyway.

Comment: Practise makes perfect. If you practise solving problems in obscure and unportable ways and focussing on insignificant optimisations, you might become great at it. Consider practising solving problems in clear and portable ways and focussing on significant optimisations.

Comment: Actually, I was *thinking* that we could save (a LITTLE BIT) of memory when swapped with that method. (Taking the fact that defining pointer is also using SOME memory blocks). I have not researched about that, and just was writing as just. 

Yeah I may be wrong. And I don't practice like that . I was just experimenting. And look, I got to know that's incorrect. Yeah, I wont practice those things and do what you say, from now on. :D

Comment: @cipher: Code has to live in memory too. So yes, you might save 4 bytes on the stack. But to do so, you're going to add more than 8 bytes of code to your function. I used to write compilers for a living, and let me tell you, prematurely optimised code almost invariably runs slower, is bigger and is less maintainable than code that is clearly written and then optimised by the compiler.

Comment: "Let your compiler do premature optimisations for you" At that point, I wouldn't call the optimizations premature anymore :-)

Comment: @AndyG Indeed. It's a very minor point, but a valid one nonetheless. I'm sure the message I intended to convey would be immediately obvious to anyone not considering that minor point, though I've put some consideration into this and after a bit more consideration, will settle with something along the lines of *"Don't manually optimise what your compiler (probably) automatically optimises for you..."* with a footnote about the "probably". Any suggestions?